# compare concatenate value to object in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is the output of my person index.cshtml. I am not sure how to join the sql linq in my index.cshtml table, any ideas?

```
name    allapartments   active
john    1, 2, 3         no
mary    1               yes
```

apartments object

```
id      name
1       LA downtown apts
2       NYC downtown apts
```

would like to output:

```
name    allapartments                           active
john    LA downtown apts, NYC downtown apts         no
mary    LA downtown apts                            yes
```

person controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var apartments = db.Apartments;
    var result = from item in Persontable
                 where apartments.All(x => item.allapartments.Contains(x))
                 select item;           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

```
void Main()
{
        var personTables = new List<Persontable>{
        new Persontable{Name = "John", AllApartments = new List<int>{1, 2, 3}, Active = false},
        new Persontable{Name = "Mary", AllApartments = new List<int>{1}, Active = true},
    };

    var apartments = new List<Apartment>{
        new Apartment { Id = 1, Name = "LA downtown apts"},
        new Apartment { Id = 2, Name = "NYC downtown apts"},
    };

    var result = personTables.Select( p => new PersontableAparment{
        Name = p.Name,
        AllApartmentsNames = apartments.Where(a => p.AllApartments.Contains(a.Id)).Select(x => x.Name).ToList(),
        Active = p.Active,
    });
}

public class Persontable
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public List<int> AllApartments { get; set;}
    public bool Active {get; set;}
}

public class Apartment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class PersontableAparment 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> AllApartmentsNames { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

}
```

You can checkout a live demo [here](http://ideone.com/k0RlzR). I am assuming that

```
name    allapartments   active
john    1, 2, 3         no
mary    1               yes
```

is the data in the Persontable table. Please note that I am using the `PersontableApartment` class to model the output that you want. Please take it as accepted answer if you find it useful.